# std::unordered_map, can you access the elements in a bucket with its bucket number?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

for `std::unordered_map`, can you access the elements in some bucket `i`
if its `bucket_size` is not zero?

Comment: Look here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map and scroll down to the "Bucket Interface" section.

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `std::unordered_map::begin(bucket_num)` or `std::unordered_map::cbegin(bucket_num)` to get the iterator pointing to the the first element to that bucket and iterate to the end of the bucket 
`std::unordered_map::end(bucket_num)`

```
for ( auto it = u_map.begin(bucket_num); it!= u_map.end(bucket_num); ++it)
{
   cout<<it->first<<", "<<it->second<<endl;
}
```