# How to print all the elements of given bucket number in c++ unordered_set?

Tags: c++, hashtable, unordered-set

I have a `unordered_set<string> ht` in c++ of which a given bucket number say x, I have to print all the elements in that given bucket of the ht[x] ie I am trying to print all elements in given bucket number x.
The last else block has it :

```
unordered_multiset<string>ht;
ll m;
cin>>m;
ht.reserve(m);
ll q;
cin>>q;
while (q--){
    string cmd;
    cin>>cmd;
    if(cmd=="add"){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        if(ht.find(s)==ht.end()){
            ht.insert(s);
        }
    }else if(cmd=="del"){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        if(ht.find(s)!=ht.end()){
            auto it = ht.find(s);
            ht.erase(it);
        }
    }else if(cmd=="find"){
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        if(ht.find(s)!=ht.end()){
            cout<<"yes"<<'\n';
        }else{
            cout<<"no"<<'\n';
        }
    }else{
        ll x;
        cin>>x;
        auto it = ht.begin(x);
        for(; it!=ht.end(x);it++){
            cout<<*it<<' ';
        }
        cout<<'\n';
    }
```

Comment: what did you try? what problem did you encounter? use `begin(x)` and `end(x)` and write a loop

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set#Bucket_interface

Comment: @idclev463035818 can begin  do that I don't know much about it can you please explain me further.

Comment: I dont know what further you need to get explained, thats why it would be best if you show what you tried and try to ask a more specific question. (btw I never used it myself, I just read here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set and what I found looks rather straightforward)

Comment: possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043034/stdunordered-map-can-you-access-the-elements-in-a-bucket-with-its-bucket-numb

Comment: Please stop doing `ll`. There is no reason to introduce a typedef for `long long` unless you want to make your code unreadable.

Comment: @Evg That's coming straight from my competitive template so, I apologize for that apart from that I think it's readable.

Comment: @Evg That's coming straight from my competitive template so, I apologize for that apart from that I think it's readable.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? It looks like it should work. Why are you declaring `it` outside of the `for` loop? I suggest `for(auto it = ht.begin(x), end=ht.end(x); it != end; ++it)` instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close since OP doesn't clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `begin(<bucket number>)` and `end(<bucket number>)` member functions can be used to iterate over elements in a specific bucket. The `bucket_count()` member function returns the number of buckets. So:

```
#include <unordered_set>

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<int> foo;

    for(size_t bno = 0; bno < foo.bucket_count(); ++bno) {
        for(auto bit = foo.begin(bno), end = foo.end(bno); bit != end; ++bit) {
            const auto& element = *bit;
            // do stuff with element
        }
    }
}
```